# Files uploading and attaching mess using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Finally I give up thinking about uploading after trying different ways.
Here is the requirement, I have a 3 step process where I implemented them using 3 web forms.

In the second step I added 5 file upload control to collect the file names to upload. After submitting 2nd step I create a session to store these upload controls.

Finally in 3rd step after submitting finish button, I have to upload all the files that were stored in the session and attach to a mail and send it to respective department.

I am able to accomplish this task if the user is uploading 1 or 2 files, but the form is hanging if the upload files count is 3 or more.

I am not sure if I have to use threads to upload and wait till the uploading is done. Can some one throw some ideas please?

Thank you,
Kris.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm, you are uploading the files and saving them in session? If so, that is a very bad idea. Your server will be out of memory in no time.

Consider saving the files to a temporary location on the web server instead.

Comment: I am just saving the upload controls to sessions not the actual files.
I am not uploading until the final submit in step3.